# Cannot connect to localhost:3306 on MySQL Workbench on Mac

Tags: mysql, macos, localhost, mysql-workbench

This is something that is recently happening. I don't know if it is due to updating my MAC OS. I am at macOS Catalina 10.15.4.

When I try to test my connection to localhost on 3306 I get the following:

```
Failed to Connect to MySQL at localhost:3306 with user root
```

If I go into System Settings I see the following:

[image]

If I try to start it the colored LEDs briefly go GREEN before going back to RED.

From the command line I have tried other solutions I have seen such as:

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/support-files/mysql.server start
```

I get the following error:

```
Starting MySQL
. ERROR! The server quit without updating PID file (/usr/local/mysql/data/lester2s-Mini.pid).
```

Any thoughts on how I can get this working again?

Here is what I found at /var/log/system.log:

```
May  7 13:28:06 lester2s-Mini xpcproxy[3576]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
May  7 13:28:06 lester2s-Mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[3576]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2
May  7 13:28:06 lester2s-Mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
May  7 13:28:12 lester2s-Mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld): This service is defined to be constantly running and is inherently inefficient.
May  7 13:28:12 lester2s-Mini xpcproxy[3582]: libcoreservices: _dirhelper_userdir: 557: bootstrap_look_up returned (ipc/send) invalid destination port
May  7 13:28:12 lester2s-Mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld[3582]): Service exited with abnormal code: 2
May  7 13:28:12 lester2s-Mini com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.oracle.oss.mysql.mysqld): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.
```

Comment: A "Mac" as in Apple Macintosh is not to be confused with [MAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address) which is an acronym.

Comment: You'll need to check the MySQL error logs, wherever those are. Usually `/var/log`, `/usr/local/mysql/` or visible through the "Console" application.